# Text Decoration + Python - is there a way?

Tags: python, console

Is there a way in python to turn text blue or make it bigger or...something?

Comment: Way too vague.  Are you talking about console output?

Comment: Text where?  The console?  A Tkinter text widget?

Comment: I guess, you are asking about IDLE. If yes, then you can change the settings under Options.

Comment: Which console of which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [curses module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). Not sure you can change the font size, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use escape sequences

```
print "^[[0;31;40mColor"
```

whereas the ^[ is a single character which can be produced by pressing first ctrl-v and then ESC.

Answer (score 1):

For coding the escape sequences I've been using the colorama package

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

It works pretty well, just make sure you check for its existence or you'll setup a script on a new machine and not be able to run it.